# Being a good secret keeper: protection against mind manipulation

Tags: dnd-3.5e

In the D&D 3.5 universe, there are lots of spells and magical effects that read your mind, read and modify your memory, or otherwise force you to unveil the secrets you've heard.

I'm looking for the most complete list of non-removable sources of immunity to such things, most likely PrC class abilities.

I guess the Occult Slayer PrC's immunity to mind-affecting effects is a good start but

1. I don't know if it's enough;
2. I want the character to be friendly to everyone.

EDIT: my aim is to keep other people's secrets safe. Like "you can tell me, sure, it's not gonna leak from me". When I talk about secrets I've heard, it's not an idiom. I partially care about things I did ("I can come with you for that messon, nothing's gonna leak from me" - but some "who killed the guards?" divination might still work).

Comment: See God Blooded template particular Vecna Blooded in the MM5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Occult Slayer *is* great for this

The Occult Slayer’s Blank Thoughts class feature does sound ideal for your purposes: it’s preventing anyone from prying secrets directly from your brain, and it’s Extraordinary, so no one can shut it down or suppress it. Quite possibly one of the “hardest” forms of protection in the game.

#### If your mind is your fortress, make sure you can stuff as much in there as possible: Autohypnosis

I strongly recommend training Autohypnosis, if you can. That way you can memorize even very long texts, avoiding the need to keep a hard copy that could get stolen.

#### Broader Protection: *Mind Blank*

The spell *mind blank* is almost-perfect immunity to snooping, seeing as it covers all [Mind-Affecting] effects **and** Divination effects that try to learn about you, explicitly covering “all devices and spells that detect, influence, or read emotions or thoughts.” With *mind blank* up, you literally need worry only about things that say they work despite *mind blank* specifically; if it doesn’t mention *mind blank* by name, it won’t work. Even the [*know secrets* salient divine ability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#knowSecrets) doesn’t break it.

*Mind blank*’s only real vulnerabilities are *dispel magic* and *antimagic field*/Dead Magic Zones. If someone takes down your *mind blank*, particularly if you only prepared one for the day thanks to its 24-hour duration, you might be in trouble. Boosting your caster level is always good, as are things like a Ring of Counterspells keyed to *greater dispel magic*. Master Abjurer (Master Specialist option, *Complete Mage*) gets a hefty bonus to preventing their buffs from being dispelled, for example.

If you can get *mind blank* as a Supernatural Ability, it becomes immune to dispelling and you therefore only need worry about *antimagic field* or dead magic zones. The Dweormerkeeper<sup>1</sup> prestige class from the *Complete Divine* web enhancement can turn any spell into a Supernatural Ability, for example; there may be other ways to get Su *mind blank* as well.

If you somehow get *mind blank* as an Extraordinary Ability or Salient Divine Ability, then it even works in an *antimagic field*. I doubt either is possible though. The Occult Slayer’s Blank Thoughts is better in these situations.

#### Vulnerability You Can’t Do Much About: Gods of Secrets

Between the two of these, all you need worry about are running afoul of deities’ portfolios. These can’t give the deity direct access to your thoughts, but they might discover things you’ve done, objects you’re hiding, and so on: any time something leaves your head and becomes a part of the external world, there’s probably a related deity who knows about it. Remember that there are gods of secrets out there; literally the act of keeping a secret itself informs the god about it.

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Dweormerkeeper is easily in the top-10 most-powerful prestige classes in the game, and probably should be banned at the overwhelming majority of tables (in addition to being impossible to dispel, Supernatural Abilities also have no components – an Su *wish*, for example, does not cost XP).

Comment: I'm not worried about deities nor about anything that could as well target the one who told my character things. I'm more worried of "you, you betrayed me" events.
AMF also usually hampers their divinations. Dead magic could be circumvented by a shoadowwave user. So I'm looking for Su or possibly Ex. Dweomerkeeper is banned from my game :)

Comment: @Zachiel as it very well should be! Mine too.

Comment: I don't get how you're interpreting *know secrets* to be prevented by *mind blank*. It says it works like *legend lore*, which isn't a mind-reading spell, so saying *know secrets* works by reading thoughts would be a house rule. The description of *mind blank* is ambiguously written regarding "gathering information", but the limitations on *wish* et al make it clear that it only protects against gathering info that comes their mind, so it wouldn't foil *legend lore*.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I would argue that's not clear at all. *Mind blank* states that "This spell protects against all [...] information gathering by divination spells or effects," which certainly would include *legend lore*. As far as *wish*, it says "*Mind blank* even foils [...] *wish* spells when they are used in such a way as to [...] gain information about [the subject of *mind blank*]." It's not just from the mind, it's immunity to divination too. I'll agree that this gets screwy in corner cases (and that immunity to two+ schools of magic is imbalanced), but this is what it says.

Comment: We appear to be reading the text for *mind blank* differently. This is what I'm reading: "Mind blank even foils […] wish spells when they are used in such a way as to affect the subject’s mind or to gain information about it," where "it" is "the subject's mind", not "the subject".

Comment: @SevenSidedDie OK, I can see that reading, but even then it would apply only to *wish*, which is a **very** powerful spell and the introduction of the sentence by *wish* et al. makes it clear that just because *mind blank* usually foils mind-affecting and divinatory effects, *wish* et al. need to be addressed separately since they are so powerful. I don't think it's automatic that you can extrapolate back from *wish* to other, less powerful spells (read: *legend lore*). Certainly the preceding sentences are quite absolute about blocking anything trying to find out about you.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Of course, I also think hard-and-fast rules for deities are just dumb in the first place and would never even bother considering the lists of Salient Divine Abilities and what they can do if I have a god directly intervening in the plot. And by that notion, rather than the RAW one, yes of course I'd have Know Secrets ignore *mind blank*. I don't like blanket immunities to begin with.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it falls under "WotC is bad at precise writing", but it's such a minor point.

Comment: I would also add that the Holy Liberator from Complete Divine has the ability Aura of Resolve, which is extraordinary and protects against mind control. It won't do much against mind reading, though. While this has no advantage compared to Blank Thoughts, in situations where Occult Slayer does not work this might be good.

Comment: @KRyan maybe Obie's addition would be a nice improvement to your answer, maybe it's better to ping Obie so that they write their own answer. (Who won? Who's next?) You decide! [cit.]

Answer (score 9):

Keeping secrets by gaining immunity to mind-affecting effects is relatively easy. The aforementioned *mind blank* spell is way high on the list, but so is just playing a creature who's *naturally* immune to mind-affecting effects. The adu'ja from *Dragon* #317 is a LA +2, no-racial-HD plant; the feytouched from the *Fiend Folio* is a LA +1, no-racial-HD fey with the extraordinary ability immune to mind-affecting effects; and *Libris Mortis* has a pay-the-money-and-XP-to-get-it necropolitan template to become undead.

Combine this with the feat Live My Nightmare (*UA* 94) to deter divination spells for added protection.

The following are not forever, and they're spells, so they might be of limited utility to you.

The programmed trigger option of the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell *programmed amnesia* (*SC* 162-3) could be activated by a mental probe and then rewrite your brain; the spell's permanent (although not instantaneous).

The 4th-level initiate of Vecna spell *Vecna's courier* (*Dragon* #342 56) shoves a secret message that the shovee doesn't remember but the shover does into the shovee's brain; mundane means *won't* get that out of you--a password is needed. It lasts 1 day per caster level.

The 2nd-level Pal spell *loyal vassal* (*SC* 134) turns a mind-affecting effects' standard orders into *suicidal* orders, which often triggers another saving throw, but only if the order is "an attempt to make a loyal vassal" "harm [the caster] or anyone else affected by this spell"--so a liberal definition of *harm* is needed. It lasts 10 minutes per level.

Top off everything with the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *mind of the labyrinth* (*DM* 70) and, if you're seriously hardcore, the 3rd-level cleric spell *infallible servant* (*EoE* 27) and things should be pretty safe in your noggin. Both last 1 hour per caster level.

By the way, a particular campaign might allow swashbucklers to seduce to learn secrets as a function of the Bluff skill. Therefore one should remain hostile and unattracted to those who swing from chandeliers. Be especially wary of the Brd7/Swb4 who can succeed on the DC 70 Bluff checks to extract unutterable secrets from hostile characters.

**Addition:** *Dragon* #340 presents on page 55 moon-warded ranger substitution levels. The 11th-level moon-warded ranger substitution level grants the indomitable mind class feature, a supernatural ability granting immunity to "mind-affecting spells and abilities" *except* harmless ones (calling out *bless* and *heroism* specifically), which is a tough and interesting trade-off (not an extraordinary effect like the occult slayer's but still being able to get morale effects). It means taking *ranger* all the way to 11, but it also means *not* having to take occult slayer.

Comment: I admittedly posed no limitations on my question, unfortunately I have no access to any of those resources, except for Loyal Vassal which I was already using at that time. Nice research effort and good list of things, however.